# Remote Collaborative Authoring - WebDav

Tags: webdav

I have a question about WebDav and the remote collaborative authoring.

I have to implement WebDav in my iOS application to communicate with a cloud server which is configured with the WebDav protocole. I have found on GitHub a WebDav library for iOS, no problem for that.

From there, I know that WebDav provides different useful types of web request, such as download, upload, delete and more.

I read that with WebDav, there is also the possibility to make a remote collaborative authoring, such as Google Drive documents and the collaborative edition. But I don't know how this is working with WebDav.

If someone heard about something and can give me some tracks of search, it would be great !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Webdav and Google Drive are unrelated technologies. I understand that recent versions of MS Office support collaborative editing of documents on webdav servers, although i havent seen it in action.